# Using Telnet in Windows 10?

Tags: windows, networking, windows-10, http, telnet

I'm learning some HTTP and need to use Telnet for testing purposes.
I tried almost every possible input I found on the Internet, but it doesn't help,
I first open Telnet command window, then Enter: `telnet www.bing.com 80`
but when I hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>, it says:

```
Invalid Command. type ?/help for help
```

In the help menu there is `o` to

```
open hostname [port] ----->connect to hostname (default port 23).
```

So I tried `o www.bing.com 80`
but it just says

```
Connecting To www.bing.com...
```

it last long, and then fails. I also tried combining `telnet` command with `o`, didn't resolve also.

Comment: It has been several days since we heard from you. Have you made any progress?

Comment: Mohammed, any feedback?

Comment: It doesn't work for me. I needed telnet in particular.

Comment: Just to double-check, did you ensure that you [enabled telnet on your Windows 10 computer](https://www.rootusers.com/how-to-enable-the-telnet-client-in-windows-10/)?  If so, the command `telnet google.com 80` should definitely work.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you are going to utilize telnet, you don't need to type the **www** with the host name.  Using `telnet google.com 80` should suffice.

To be honest, if you are on a Windows 10 machine it would probably be easier to use the similar capability with the `Test-NetConnection` function that is built into PowerShell:

[image: PowerShell]